# MySQL Left Join use IN to compare only values present in which second table should give only those values which are present in first table

Tags: mysql

How can I write a MySQL query using LEFT JOIN and IN to compare values between two tables, where the second table should only provide values that are present in the first table?

I need to ensure that the query retrieves only the matching values between the two tables.

PS: I request you to pls revert back whatever your thoughts are instead of giving votes as it would help me next time :)

Comment: please provide sample data, expected results and your best query attempt. the question is completely unclear as it is posed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the below query:

`SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3 FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND t2.column1 IN (SELECT column1 FROM table1);`

As mentioned in comment it would be better if you could post some sample data or your output to have better understanding